# Connecting to Bluetooth when trying to get Current Geographic Location in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I had done A Simple Application to Record Current Geographic Location and Display it on Mobile Screen then its working fine in j2me emulator but when application installed in mobile(Nokia Asha 210) it installed and opening directly to connecting to bluetooth. It is opening the bluetooth settings where the problem i cant understand so i need help regarding this issue..

This is my Entire Code....

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Alert;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.AlertType;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.StringItem;
import javax.microedition.location.Location;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationListener;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationProvider;
import javax.microedition.location.QualifiedCoordinates;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletStateChangeException;

public class LocationWithPolling extends MIDlet implements Runnable, CommandListener {
Form mainform;
Thread t;
LocationProvider lp;
Display display;
StringItem latitude;
StringItem longitude;
Command exitCommand=new Command("Exit",Command.OK,0);

protected void destroyApp(boolean arg0) {}
protected void pauseApp() {}

protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException 
{
    mainform=new Form("Location Polling");
    latitude=new StringItem("Latitude:","N/A");
    longitude=new StringItem("Longitude:","N/A");
    Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(mainform);
    mainform.append(latitude);
    mainform.append(longitude);
    mainform.addCommand(exitCommand);
    mainform.setCommandListener(this);
    t=new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}
   public void run() 
    {
    try{
        lp = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);
        while(true)
        {
            Location loc=lp.getLocation(5000);
            QualifiedCoordinates c=loc.getQualifiedCoordinates();
            latitude.setText(String.valueOf(c.getLatitude()));
            longitude.setText(String.valueOf(c.getLongitude()));
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
     {
     Alert alert = 
       new Alert("Error", "Could not retrieve location!", null, AlertType.ERROR);                                      
         display.setCurrent(alert);
    }    
   }
public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState) { }
public void commandAction(Command cmd, Displayable arg1) 
{
    if(cmd==exitCommand)
    {
        notifyDestroyed();
    }
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Asha phones do not have internal GPS, so it attempts to connect to a bluetooth GPS, and you apparently have none paired with the phone. That is why I think it opens BT settings. If you had one, it would connect to it.